# Construct complex gantt chart

Tags: r, plot, graphics, gantt-chart

I have been using advice on this thread [Gantt charts with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550341/gantt-charts-with-r)

to develop something like [this](http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/infographic/news/companies/airline-merger/020113-airlines-v3b.png), [this](http://aviationweek.com/site-files/aviationweek.com/files/uploads/2015/02/us%20major%20airlines%20merger%20chart%20pic%20REV%20B.jpeg) or [this](http://www.motherjones.com/files/images/big-bank-theory-chart-large.jpg).

I have been failing miserably. I am not even certain on the data structure that I should follow. I believe the structure should look something like below:

```
  start_date, end_date, ID_prior, ID_now, ID_post
```

Comment: Another example http://darwiniana.org/trees.htm. I think that an "inverted" classification tree might work as well.

Comment: Look into [Sankey Plots](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/example_build_network_sankey.html).