# How to change label width in mermaid Gantt chart

Tags: r, mermaid

I'm trying to use `DiagrammeR` to create a Gantt chart, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999300/2761575).

But if the section names are too long they spill into the chart.  Here's an example.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("
  gantt
  dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
  title Project timeline

  section A ridiculously long section name
  create data structures                      :done,     frame1,     2019-01-01, 2019-02-28

  section Another long section name
  refactor mistakes in data structures        :active,     frame2,     after frame1, 12w

  section Section 3
  Write code                                  :active,     first_1,    after frame1, 2019-06-30
  Party                                       :crit,       first_2,    after first_1,  7d
  ")
```

[image]

Anyone know how to adjust the width of the section label column?  `?mermaid` offers no explanation.  And this help page (https://mermaidjs.github.io/gantt.html) only says "TBD" in the syntax sections.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a `<br>` in the title of the section to force a line break:

```
section A ridiculously <br> long section <br> name
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find any correct answer about this question.
Then I found an ugly workaround.
I add a task that start 1 or more days before and it's length is the days that start before

```
.:01/01/2022, 2d
```

Change the date and number of days to enlarge the title column.

It's ugly I know, but it works.

Comment: really ugly, but it works. Thank you.