# renderDiagrammeR mermaid diagram size in a Shiny Document

Tags: r, shiny, diagrammer, mermaid

I am trying to embed the `DiagrammeR` example from [Gantt charts with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550341/gantt-charts-with-r) into a Shiny document. There are two problems I am trying to solve:

1) Make the font in the `textAreaInput` Courier New, and preferably smaller size. (I got this solution an hour after posting by adding the following to the top of the Rmd just under the final `---`:)

```
<style>
textarea {
  font-family: Courier New;
}
</style>
```

2) Make the `mermaid` Gantt Chart much bigger so I can see dynamic changes (I tried adding `width=900` and so on but no luck. The problem seems to be limited to RStudio, as the whitespace around the Gantt Chart is not there if I open this Shiny document in Chrome.)

The code for entire Shiny document is here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

````
---
title: "Gantt Chart with Mermaid & DiagrammeR"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(DiagrammeR)

inputPanel(
  textAreaInput("inText", NULL, width="900px", rows=15, value="
gantt
dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
title A Very Nice Gantt Diagram

section Basic Tasks
This is completed             :done,          first_1,    2014-01-06, 2014-01-08
This is active                :active,        first_2,    2014-01-09, 3d
Do this later                 :               first_3,    after first_2, 5d
Do this after that            :               first_4,    after first_3, 5d

section Important Things
Completed, critical task      :crit, done,    import_1,   2014-01-06,24h
Also done, also critical      :crit, done,    import_2,   after import_1, 2d
Doing this important task now :crit, active,  import_3,   after import_2, 3d
Next critical task            :crit,          import_4,   after import_3, 5d

section The Extras
First extras                  :active,        extras_1,   after import_4, 3d
Second helping                :               extras_2,   after extras_1, 20h
More of the extras            :               extras_3,   after extras_1, 48h
  ")
)

renderDiagrammeR({
  mermaid(
     paste0(input$inText)
  )  
})
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made slight (style) changes (hope you don't mind).

1) Change the font and it size in *css* chunk *textarea*. With the *!important* rule you can override the particular (default) property in *css* Bootstrap. Also, you can adjust the width/height of the *textarea* in the same *css* chunk or in the *textAreaInput*.

2) You can adjust the width/height of the diagram in *DiagrammeROutput*. Finally, pass the values from *input$inText* to *output$diagram*.

````
---
title: "Gantt Chart with Mermaid & DiagrammeR"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{css textarea, echo = FALSE}
textarea {
  # width: 900px !important;
  # height: 440px !important;
  font-family: Courier New !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  background-color: #cccccc !important;
  # background-color: lightgrey !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 10px solid #ffffff !important;
}
```

```{r gantt-chart, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(DiagrammeR)

shiny::textAreaInput(inputId = "inText", label = NULL, width = "900px", height = "370px", rows = 15, value = "
gantt
dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
title A Very Nice Gantt Diagram

section Basic Tasks
This is completed             :done,          first_1,    2014-01-06, 2014-01-08
This is active                :active,        first_2,    2014-01-09, 3d
Do this later                 :               first_3,    after first_2, 5d
Do this after that            :               first_4,    after first_3, 5d

section Important Things
Completed, critical task      :crit, done,    import_1,   2014-01-06,24h
Also done, also critical      :crit, done,    import_2,   after import_1, 2d
Doing this important task now :crit, active,  import_3,   after import_2, 3d
Next critical task            :crit,          import_4,   after import_3, 5d

section The Extras
First extras                  :active,        extras_1,   after import_4, 3d
Second helping                :               extras_2,   after extras_1, 20h
More of the extras            :               extras_3,   after extras_1, 48h
")

DiagrammeR::DiagrammeROutput(outputId = "diagram", width = "950px", height = "auto")

output$diagram <- 
  DiagrammeR::renderDiagrammeR({
    DiagrammeR::mermaid(
      base::paste0(input$inText)
      )
    })
```
````

[image]