# Is there a way to create this chart in R?

Tags: r, gantt-chart

I have tried to create this gantt chart in R but I am not a fan of the multiple rows per task. I want to try to have a row per person assigned to a task instead. This is an image of what I mean:

[image: Chart]

As you can see from the image, the projects are listed on the left and the tasks are listed on the right. The tasks are also color coded based off of the person doing the task. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550341/gantt-charts-with-r) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.